# Error on deploying a web application by WinHost

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, sharepoint, sensenet

I have build a sensenet (a simple Asp.net MVC web application) which I need to deploy on my shared hosting account by winhost. I have deployed the application by FTP, and I even do not know whether it was right or wrong. 
Now when I'm trying to browse that site  it shows an error:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20"/>
<trust level="Full"/>
```

Please remark me, treat me as someone who has never deployed any website.

Comment: Remove the trust level full in your web.config and republish?

Comment: Still their is same error http://labelcms.com/sensenet